# Anything better than CruiseControl for .Net CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, cruisecontrol.net

I've been asked to set up yet another CruiceControl environment for yet another client.  I realized that I've been using CC for *years* without really looking around for competitors.  Is there anything else that's sprung up that does the job equally well or better for .Net apps?

Comment: removed [bamboo] tag added by Tony Lambert. This should be an open question, right?

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647621/cruise-control-net-alternatives

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is a very good CI server. (and the "Professional" edition is free)

I've been using it for over a year for building .NET projects, and I must say it's way better than CC.NET IMHO.

Strong points are:

- Very easy to configure (web based GUI)
- Distributed system (you can have several build agents on multiple machines to distribute the build process)
- Built-in support for many source control systems
- ... check the website. The product is awesome ...

Comment: +1 for TeamCity, I was up and running in no time.

Comment: Also +1 for TeamCity. It's really great, works on all machines flawlessly (both Windows and Linux) and with all build systems and unit test frameworks we use here.

Comment: Another +1 for TeamCity. Switched from CC.NET to CC.rb to TeamCity. Tried a lot of competing products both free and commercial after CC.rb, TeamCity was the simplest while providing a lot of power.

Comment: its only free up to 20 projects

Answer (score 8):

If you haven't seen it you might want to check out the [Continuous Integration Feature Matrix](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/CI+Feature+Matrix) which lists virtually ever CI server out there.

I work on the Java version of CruiseControl and these days I work for Urbancode who makes [AnthillPro](http://www.anthillpro.com/). From that perspective the right tool depends on the scope of what you're looking for. If you're just looking for fast feedback after a build lots of tools will work. If you're looking to setup a build grid then a there's a smaller group of tools. If you want to track dependencies between projects and deployments to multiple environments then you're in an even smaller group.

Comment: +1 for the link to the feature matrix, helpful!

Answer (score 2):

[AppVeyor CI](http://www.appveyor.com) is worth looking at. It's a hosted Continuous Integration service for .NET developers and it's free for open-source projects.

Answer (score 1):

[Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/) is an alternative... it also is provided as part of a integrated toolset or cloud service. They include Subversion, Jira (task/bug logging), confluence (WIKI), and other coding tools - see the link.

The are available as a managed service or you can purchase the suite and run it internally. Their packages are extended to use a single sign on system and centrally administrated.

Answer (score 1):

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is really a good solution.

[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) is also a really great tool, and even if it is essentially dedicated to Java projects, it can be used on .Net or C++ projects quite easily now...

Answer (score 0):

Why not MSBuild if you are building .Net projects? 
Do you have a TeamFoundationServer, if so, TeamFoundationBuild and MSbuild are a definite possibility.